# I want to delete the prefix "HTTP_" of nginx proxy_set_header

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

When using nginx's proxy_set_header, `HTTP_` is added to the prefix of its own header. Please tell me how to prevent this.

```
proxy_set_header exmaple_key example_value;
```

As a result, the header name acquired is `HTTP_EXAMPLE_KEY`.

I want this to be `EXAMPLE_KEY`.